# Input text showing on next row

Tags: css

On http://www.bigbasket.com, the Input for "Qty" is coming on the next row in case of IE9.
Its fine on IE7/8, FF and Chrome. But for some reason it is breaking on IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be the fact that you are not using the label correctly. The Label should contain the text "qty", and the input should not be inside the label. E.g.

```
<label for="p10000159_qty">Qty:</label>
<input id="p10000159_qty" class="qtyTxtField" name="pqty" maxLength="2" value="1" type="text">
```

**EDIT** it works if you either reduce the width of `.qtyTextField` by 3px, or take off `margin-left:3px`. It is shifting onto the next row because there's not enough room on that row for IE.

Comment: `input` elements can be placed inside `label`s. The usage is correct. The text should probably be inside the `label` element, though I'm not entirely sure if that is causing the problem here.

Comment: If you validate the HTML, for each label you'll get this error:
*'end tag for element "label" which is not open'*
[Check W3C Validation for the site](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbigbasket.com%2F)
But you're right, it's not the reason why it's not displaying properly in ie9, but it might help make it more consistent across browsers.

Comment: I tried the above approach, but it still didn't worked.
I think IE9 is applying some sort of default styling. Not sure though.

Comment: Just reduce the width of `.qtyTextField` by 3px or remove the `margin-left: 3px` off.